# database driven codeigniter navbar

Tags: php, css, codeigniter, twitter-bootstrap

I am new with CodeIgniter and have been told that it is the way to go.

I have read the user manual a few times now but don't seem to understand one thing which is I wanted to do a navbar driven from the database. I found a few posts on here saying about a method that I have implemented but no matter what I do, it just doesn't seem to work for me. what I have done so far:

Created a table with :

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `app_routes` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `slug` varchar(192) collate utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `controller` varchar(64) collate utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),
  KEY `slug` (`slug`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
```

Added to `route.php` file

```
$route[ 'default_controller' ]  = 'home';
$route[ '404_override' ]        = 'error404';

require_once( BASEPATH .'database/DB'. EXT );
$db =& DB();
$query = $db->get( 'app_routes' );
$result = $query->result();
foreach( $result as $row )
{
    $route[ $row->slug ]                 = $row->controller;
    $route[ $row->slug.'/:any' ]         = $row->controller;
    $route[ $row->controller ]           = 'error404';
    $route[ $row->controller.'/:any' ]   = 'error404';
}
```

Set up a controller with:

```
<?php
class Home extends CI_Controller {

    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->view('smooth/header.php');
    $this->load->view('smooth/navbar.php');
        $this->load->view('smooth/index.php');
        $this->load->view('smooth/footer.php');

        }
}
?>
```

In the database I have under controller `home` and as page `contact`

When I visit my site via my domain name only I see the frontpage but if I add the `index.php/home` to it I get nothing or `index.php/home/contact` nothing either

The path to my `index.php` files as situated in my `domain/application/views/themes/smooth/index.php`

Can anyone help with what I am missing please or what the problem is?

Comment: Seems a little odd for anyone to describe CodeIgniter as "the way to go" when EllisLabs are no longer actively maintaining it and no-one else appears to have yet offered to take over.

Comment: Also, you really need to show your view file as well, as it's quite likely the problem is there.

Comment: @MatthewDaly, i questioned about codeigniter as not being active and it was said that there libraries would save a lot of time and was good against security.

Comment: in view/themes/smooth/index.php i have only writen index page and in view/themes/smooth/contact.php i have contact page. i am trying to call them by going to mydomain/index.php/home/ and mydomain/index.php/home/contact but none work

Comment: Any framework will save you a lot of development time compared to using plain old PHP. Since CodeIgniter is no longer being actively maintained, then if a vulnerability is found in it, then it will likely not be patched. There are plenty of modern, actively maintained PHP frameworks around.

Comment: Also, why on earth are you doing a database query in `routes.php`? That **really** does not belong there.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't pass the routes to the view.

Without seeing the view in question I can't tell if there's an issue there, but you need to pass the data through like this:

```
$this->load->model('yourmodel');
$routes = $this->yourmodel->getRoutes();
$data = array(
    'routes' => $routes
);  
$this->load->view('smooth/header.php');
```

The database query goes in a model, so you will need to define that, and a method to return the data - here I've represented that model as `yourmodel` and the method to call as `getRoutes`. You should not, under *any* circumstances, be placing your database query in `routes.php`.